# Clamp 3.3V Raspberry pi square wave

Tags: raspberry-pi, mosfet-driver

I have Sqaure Wave coming from raspberry pi. It switches from 3.3V to 0 with 50% duty cycle. I would like to connect 3V from external power supply and clamp this output so that it start switching between 3V and 6.3V. Can this be done?

I would like to use this to drive a MOSFET gate which has a threshold of 5V.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want 3V as PWM low level ?

Comment: @LongPham If 3V is below your minimum design conduction level you save on risetime/turnon by not fully discharging the FET gate.

Comment: The best solution is probably to find a MOSFET with a low enough threshold voltage to be (nearly) fully on at 3.3v.  Or you can look for a MOSFET gate driver.  The absolute last thing you want to do is to try to inject an offset voltage below the pi's ground to raise the output; while theoretically possible, in practice that is a recipe for difficulty and damaged parts.

Comment: sounds a lot like XY problem.